# Keeping SQL Dry

Tags: sql, mysql, dry

Here is a MySQL query I'm running:

```
-- get the sid of every supplier who does not supply both a red and green part
SELECT Suppliers.sid, Parts.color
FROM Suppliers
JOIN Catalog ON Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
JOIN Parts ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid
WHERE Suppliers.sid NOT IN (
    SELECT Suppliers.sid
    FROM Suppliers
    JOIN Catalog ON Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
    JOIN Parts ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid
    WHERE Parts.color IN ('red', 'green')
    GROUP BY Suppliers.sid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Parts.color) = 2
)
ORDER BY Suppliers.sid DESC;
```

As you can see, this is repeated twice:

```
FROM Suppliers
JOIN Catalog ON Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
JOIN Parts ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid
```

What can I do to only declare this once, and reference it twice? Or is this a sign that my whole query is flawed somehow?

The problem is exacerbated when I have 15 different queries I'm running with those same three lines.

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to continue to use a relationship of tables together throughout your system, then what you want to look into is called a [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)).

Comment: A view solves the problem of repeated SQL, as stated by scwagner.  It also provides a useful level of abstraction between the physical table storage and the logical appearance of the data to your application.

Comment: But be careful, a view can bite you in the bum if you use it too much, especially when the view is returning more columns than you need in your specific case or is doing a lot of unecessary joins.  If you are after straight performance sometims you just have to DRY

Answer (score 0):

A more ANSI solution I assume would work in MySQL:

```
SELECT X.sid, X.color 
  FROM (SELECT Catalog.sid, parts.color, 
               count(distinct parts.color) as distinct_color_count
          from Catalog 
               inner jOIN Parts 
                  ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid 
         where parts.color in ("red", "green")
         group by catalog.sid, parts.color)
       ) x
 where x.distinct_color_count = 2
 order by x.sid desc
```

You don't pull anything out of Suppliers but sid, and that must exist in Catalog, so use Catalog.sid instead.

Nest the select statement so you get the distinct_color_count so you can filter for it in a following step.  If you try this:

```
SELECT Catalog.sid, parts.color, 
       count(distinct parts.color) 
  from Catalog 
       inner join Parts 
          ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid 
 where parts.color in ("red", "green")
having count(distinct parts.color) = 2
 group by catalog.sid, parts.color
 order by catalog.sid ;
```

it won't work, because each row will have only one distinct color in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY up most common queries (especially common joins) with a VIEW like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=MERGE VIEW Suppliers_Catalog_Parts
AS
select *
FROM Suppliers
JOIN Catalog ON Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
JOIN Parts ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid;
```

You may want to change * to specific columns to avoid id name clashes.

There are couple of gotchas to be aware of.

First, for views with no where clause ALWAYS specify the algorithm as MERGE so that the view is stored as a query and then merged with your SQL at runtime; otherwise it can be evaluated as a temporary table (which can potentially be disastrous for generic views like this).

Secondly, some queries can't created as VIEWs - in particular if the from clause contains a subquery.  There are workarounds for this too.

If you want read more, I'm writing a series on how to write DRY SQL here:
http://blog.gruffdavies.com/2014/08/23/how-to-write-dry-sql-in-mysql-part-1-views/

HTH

Gruff